# Incorrect message "CiviCRM Security Upgrade Needed" after upgrade to 5.65.0

Tags: upgrade

Drupal 7, just updated from 5.58

The message in the system status claims the site is 5.60, though the footer says it's 5.65, and the db updates have run fine.

FWIW, on this upgrade, none of the core components got enabled as extensions, though enabling them didn't fix this issue.

This has (so far) not occurred for all similar sites, but has affected a few site with reasonably old civicrm installs (i.e. about 10 years old).

I'm mostly baffled that the system status message things the site is still 5.60, even the old civicrm-version.php file, though marked as deprecated, is correctly showing 5.65.

Comment: What do you get when you type this on the CLI? `cv api4 Domain.get +s=version`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/version-msgs-cache.json.

Comment: Thanks! The file permissions for that file were fine, so it appears to be a weird code edge case at this stage.